# How to query a Mongo collection using LangChain

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I want to query my mongo collection using LangChain.

Just like we have `SQLDatabaseChain` in LangChain to connect with a SQL database such as Postgres, do we have something similar to connect with a NoSQL database like Mongo?

I looked at the documentation and didn't find any alternative for NoSQL.

Comment: I would like to know if there is an option for CosmosDB also.